# Show that $\{x \in A : o(f,x) \ge \epsilon\}$ is closed.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Let $f: A \to \mathbb{R}$, $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a bounded function from a closed set. For any $\epsilon > 0$ show that $\{x \in A : o(f,x) \ge \epsilon\},$ where $o(f,x) := \lim_{\delta \to 0} M(x,f,\delta) - m(x,f,\delta),$ ande $M(x,f,\delta), m(x,f,\delta)$ defined as the sup and infi of the following set:
$$\{f(x) : x\in A ~\text{and} ~ |x-a|< \delta \}.$$

This is a theorem from the Spivak's book Calculus on Manifolds.
I have the feeling that Spivak's avoid to talk concepts like continuity and sup, inf, in their proofs, he enjoys most take neighbourhoods choose intervals, etc, so remains some questions on his proofs. I am trying to make my own for each thereom. So, in this step I stucked here:

Let $B:= \{x \in A : o(f,x) \ge \epsilon\}$. Lets show that $\mathbb{R} - B$ is open. Take $x \in \mathbb{R}^n - B.$ Then $x \notin A$ or $x \in A$ and $o(f,x) < \epsilon.$
The first case is easy. Now suppose $x \in A$ and $o(f,x) < \epsilon.$ This means that $f$ is continuous in $x$ by the preceed proposition of Spivak's book. Then I can choose an open ball over $x$, $B_x$ such that $f(B_x) \subset B_{f(x)}$ a open ball over $f(x).$ Then for every $z$ on this ball $o(f,z) < \epsilon.$ Then I have found an open ball enterely contained in $\mathbb{R}^n - B.$ Once it holds for every $x \in A$ and $o(f,x) < \epsilon$ and I also proved the case when $x \notin A$ (I did not include here) the statement holds.

Is this right?

---

Comment: $f$ is continuous at $x$ if $o(f,x)= 0$. Less than one $\epsilon>0$ is surely not sufficient.

Comment: @user251257 you chan choose $\epsilon$ as close to zero as possible.

Comment: Yes, $A$ must be closed, I am sorry. I dont get your hint.

Comment: For any set $S_\epsilon = \{ x \in A \mid o(f,x) \ge \epsilon\}$ the $\epsilon$ is fixed. You can't make it smaller.

Comment: @user251257 indeed, could you help more so? I can't get your hint. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, my bad, $o(f,x)$ is only upper semi continuous in $x$.

1. Let $M(x) = \lim_{\delta\to 0} M(x, f, \delta)$ and $m(x) = \lim_{\delta\to 0} m(x, f, \delta)$. Then, we have $o(f,x) = M(x) - m(x)$.
   If $M$ and $-m$ are upper semi continuous, so is $o(f,.)$. Thus, the pre-image $S_\epsilon = \{ x\in A \mid o(f,x) \ge \epsilon \}$ of  $[0,\infty)$ is also closed.
2. For upper semi continuity: I will proof it for $M$ only, as $-m(x) = \lim_{\delta\to 0} M(x, -f, \delta)$.

   Let $U_\delta(x) = \{ z \in A \mid |z-x| < \delta\}$. Let $x\in A$, $y=M(x)$, and $\epsilon>0$. Then, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $\delta' \in (0,\delta)$ we have
   $$ 0 \le M(x,f,\delta') - y < \epsilon $$
   Now for $z\in U_{\delta/3}(x)$ we have $x\in U_{\delta/3}(z) \subseteq U_{2\delta/3}(x)$ and thus
   $$ M(z) \le M(z, f, \delta/3) \le M(x, f, 2\delta/3) < y+ \epsilon. $$
   That is, $M$ is upper semi continuous. That is the same as
   $$ \limsup_{z\to x} M(z) \le M(x). $$
3. Since $o(f,.)$ is also upper semi continuous, for every sequence $(x_n)_{n\ge 1}$ in $S_\epsilon$ with limit $x$ we have
   $$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} \underbrace{o(f,x_n)}_{\ge\epsilon} \le o(f,x) $$
   and $x\in S_\epsilon$. That is, $S_\epsilon$ is closed.

Comment: thank you! I really appreciate your help. Thank you!